# Переадресация на другой хостинг

Tags: администрирование

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что людям с Украины не доступен мой сайт, потому что он расположен на yandex cloud. Возможно ли сделать переадресацию на другой домен? Например, если у человека украинское айпи или сайт не отвечает, он заходит на домен ua, который расположен на украинском хостинге. А в других случаях на ru хостинг, который расположен на yandex cloud.

Какое есть решение?

Comment: Полагаю, что понадобится отдельный proxy сервер, который будет смотреть регион пользователя и выбирать куда его направить. На основном сервере логику реализовать не выйдет, так как пользователь просто не дойдет до нее